# Putting a non GFCI downstream from a GFCI

Tags: wiring, kitchens, gfci, refrigerator, nec

I have an outlet next to my sink in a kitchen remodel. There is another outlet downstream that is located behind the refrigerator where the fridge will be plugged in. I know the outlet next to the sink needs to be GFCI however can I wire the second outlet for the fridge to the line side of the 1st outlet so as not to have my fridge on the GFCI? I've had problems with refrigeration on GFCI circuits before but I don't want to do anything dangerous or ill advised. Is there any problem with doing it this way?

Answer (score 2):

Is it dangerous? Arguably not a problem at all, as the refrigerator itself is not the type of appliance that needs GFCI, and the receptacle will be blocked by the refrigerator. It is more than 6 feet away (as the crow flies) from the sink then I think it would be technically OK under current code, but I am not 100% sure of that.

If this work will go through a regular permitting process then you may want to check with your local permitting office to find out if there is a local exception for refrigerators. You may also want to use a single receptacle rather than a duplex receptacle and add a label "Refrigerator Only" - that would make it abundantly clear to any future owner or inspector that this is a special setup.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this. You're not actually putting the fridge downstream from the GFCI (which is also possible, using the controlled terminals of the GFCI), you're just forking the power at the outlet box with pigtails to the GFCI and the unprotected power continuing to the fridge outlet.

The fridge won't be protected by the GFCI this way, of course. But that's no worse than what you've always had.